# VueJS + jQuery: dynamically creating component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm relatively new to Vue.js, trying to create a Vue component based on this [custom select menu](https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz) and am looking to add an ionicon to each list item.

Normally, I can create the icon in Vue.js with the following line (with the relevant imported icons):

```
<component class="icon" :is="name-of-icon"></component>
```

However, the custom select menu I'm trying to replicate hides the default `select` element and dynamically adds its own elements with custom CSS styling.

As a result of this, the following is not a solution as it requires me to use the default `select` styling:

```
<option v-for="option in options" :value="option">
    <component class="icon" :is="icon"></component 
    <p>{{ option }}</p>
</option>
```

Instead, I tried to add the icon using jQuery when it is styled. Putting the jQuery from the aforementioned pen into a method, `style()`:

```
<template>
    <select>
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">
            {{ option }}
        </option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    import MdPersonIcon from 'vue-ionicons/dist/md-person.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'custom-select',
        components: {MdPersonIcon},
        methods: {
            style() {
                $('select').each(function () {

                    // rest of code from pen here

                    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
                        let option = $('<li />', {
                            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
                        });
                        let text = $this.children('option').eq(i).text();
                        let $icon = $('<component>', {
                            'class': 'icon',
                            ':is': 'md-person-icon',
                        });
                        let $label = $('<p>', {
                            text: text
                        });

                        $icon.appendTo(option);
                        $label.appendTo(option);
                        option.appendTo($list);
                    }

                    // rest of code from pen here
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.style();
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    /* rest of CSS from the pen here */
    .icon {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

And usage of component being (where `options` is a String array):

```
<custom-select :options="options"></custom-select>
```

Creating an icon normally and then inspecting it produces something like:

```
<div class="ion profile-icon" data-title="Md Person Icon" data-name="md-person-icon" data-v-fc38bec4="">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="ion__svg">
        <path d="some long string"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The component was replaced with the ionicon. However, inspecting the element shows that the component was not replaced:

```
<component class="icon" :is="md-person-icon"></component>
```

I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

I am aware that I should **not** be trying to mix jQuery and Vue but I currently cannot think of another way to create a custom select menu Vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to transfer elements created by jQuery to Vue, cuz what jQuery add in runtime wont bind and not detectable by Vue, here is sample that I see your jquery code doing

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li for="option in options" :key="option.rel" :rel="option.rel">
      <component class="icon" :is="option.icon" />
      <p>{{ option.text }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
   data(){
    return {
      options:[
         {rel:'hide', text:'-- Month --', icon: 'md-person-icon'},
         {rel:'january', text:'january', icon: 'md-person-icon'},
         {rel:'february', text:'february', icon: 'md-person-icon'},
         ...
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give an example using the `select` tag? And with this solution, I don't need to include my added jQuery solution?

Comment: Codes that i wrote in template tag is what your jQuery code add to page so dont need what codes you added in style method, what i saw in your Codepan is that set `display : none` for select tags and use ul li instead. you cant add icon to select element, inspect your codepen to see select is hidden

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I can just skip the creating the `select` element and just display the actual thing I want to show?

Comment: Exactly! From what I see, select tag is source for jQuery elements builder, while we use `data` property for this purpose in vue wont need it anymore